# SelectedIndexChanged event of gridview fails to fire randomly

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, visual-studio-2005, selectedindexchanged

Hi I have a Gridview SelectedIndexChanged event. it fires on click of any row in that grid. But sometime (once in 10 tries) it doesnt fire. i have some code inside AgeGrid_SelectedIndexChanged which set the session variable. when it fails not able to get proper value.

Any Idea why it fails randomly?

i have not set EnableEventValidation="false" property for that page. And using visual studio 2005.

```
<Asp:GridView ID="agendaGrid" runat="server" Width="96%" GridLines="Both" EnableViewState="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader "
                                    OnSorting = "AgeGrid_Sorting" CssClass="GridView"  
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AgeGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                     AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" ItemTemplateType="PopUpMenu"
                                    ShowTemplateFields="true"   EnableOnClick="true" RowStyle-Font-Size="13px" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="middle"
                                    EnablePopUpClick="true" OnRowDataBound="AgeGrid_RowDataBound" AllowSorting ="true"
                                    >
</Asp:GridView>
```

Any Suggestions are welcome.
is there any thing i need to add or delete from page property or Gridview property?

Comment: It seems like you are saying randomly when clicking on it, it doesn't work?  Is it always the 10th try?

Comment: its not always on 10th try. i said in a generic point of view. it fails sometime on many try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void AgeGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
       agendaGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

may problem in binding data after paging, not eror in pagination.
May its helps you.